# Java underscore equivalent in F#?

Tags: f#, largenumber

In Java it's possible to write **1_000_000** instead of **1000000** for better readability. Is there something equivalent in F#?

Comment: It's planned: https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6628026-accept-integer-literals-like-12-345-for-readabilit

Comment: Great, I'm looking forward to that!

Comment: @Tom, I think you should write the answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was already asked on [feature request page](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6628026-accept-integer-literals-like-12-345-for-readabilit) and the current status of this chanbge request is *"planned"* and *"approved in principle"*.
So it may will be implemented in one of the next releases.

You can find more information about this request (like a summary about this feature, the motivation and suggested implementation details) on the [github page for F#](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpLangDesign/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1005-underscores-in-numeric-literals.md):

> ## Summary
>
> Allow underscores between any digits in numeric literals. This feature enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric literals, which can improve the readability of your code.
>
> For instance, if your code contains numbers with many digits, you can use an underscore character to separate digits in groups of three, similar to how you would use a punctuation mark like a comma, or a space, as a separator.
>
> ## Motivation
>
> This is a popular feature in other languages. Some other languages with a similar feature:
>
> - Perl
> - Ruby
> - Java 7
> - C++11 (use single quote)
>
> just to name a few...
>
> ## Detailed design
>
> You can place underscores only between digits. You cannot place underscores in the following places:
>
> - At the beginning or end of a number
> - Adjacent to a decimal point in a floating point literal
> - Prior to an F or L or other suffix
> - In positions where a string of digits is expected

Comment: I made this a community wiki, so someone can update this answer if the status of this feature request changes.